# In window phone 7, i want to call a PHP page in C# form filed in the phone, must get saved in the server

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a registration form in window7 phone & I want to call a PHP page in C# so that the values that i insert in the form must be saved to the server. How can I do this?

Comment: What's gone wrong with your attempt? Please be detailed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class which allows you to send HTTP requests to remote endpoints.

Here's an example:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenReadCompleted += OpenReadCompleted;
UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder("http://example.com/foo.php");
wc.OpenReadAsync(fullUri.Uri);
```

and then you would have the `OpenReadCompleted` handler which will be called when the request succeeds:

```
void OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    using (Stream responseStream = e.Result)
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // do something with the response
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot create a PHP page in C#. PHP is a totally different beast than C#.

What you probably want is a Web service that your phone app can call. Web services are very easy to create and very easy to consume from .NET applications, including phone applications.

Here's an intro article you might find useful: http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-create-web-service-in-cnet.html.

Here's an article about consuming web services from Windows Phone 7 applications: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/355937/How-to-use-webservice-in-Windows-Phone-7-applicati

And another one: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Weather-Forecast-Sample-586ef733

Good luck!